# How to do aliasing with union or possible with enum?

Tags: c, enums, unions, pointer-aliasing

I have gone through this very good article

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

but I didn't understood of aliasing with union, what I know about aliasing is with `char/ unsigned char`, which is a compiler exception according to this article. so , how I used to do aliasing with `char/ unsigned char` is like,

```
// lets say I have struct blah , having int member non_sense, cmmn_sense, intelligence...
struct blah *foo, *foo2;
unsigned char buffer [512];
foo = (struct blah *) (buffer+0);
//now accessing members
foo->non_sense = -1;
foo->non_snese = 0;
foo->intelligence =1;
// now we can use another struct after that ..
foo2 = (struct blah*) (buffer + sizeof(struct blah));
```

Please correct me if I am wrong some where :)

**Q.So how can I do the same with union?**

**NOTE** I didn't encountered with union much, so I don't know its proper use too.

I have also searched for aliasing with `enum`, but didn't understood much ,

**Q.If possible with enum how will we do that?**

Sorry for my English, not that good and please openly suggest correction for my misconception or terminology in my question to correct ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, almost any pointer (including your examples) is unsafe (except if it accessed by `char`).

Below is safe (access by char pointer):

```
struct blah x;
char *y = (char *)&x;

for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x); i++)
   printf("[%zu] = %hhd\n", i, y[i];
```

The correct way is to `memcpy` buffer into the struct or to have char array as one of the union members.

```
struct a
{
    int a;
    short b;
    char x[2];
    double z[3];
};


union b
{
    unsigned char buffer[512];
    struct a sa[512/32];
};

double foo(char *x)
{
    struct a c;
    memcpy(&c, x, sizeof(c));
    return c.z[0];
}

double bar(void)
{
    union b c;

    read_from_uart(&c, 512);

    return c.sa[5].z[1];
}
```

> Q.If possible with enum how will we do that?
> Enum is an integer. Same rules as for integers.

Comment: 0__________ -- Okey, pretty much clear about it, what about enum? can you give any example for enum?

Comment: `enum` s are simple `int`s. Nothing special.